# Shiny HTML Embedded app.R Not Accepting Height Attributes https://mytoybox.online

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have a web page running on a shiny server [My Toy Box](https://mytoybox.online).  There is one shiny application that I want to be 100% wide and 940px high.  Until this week, I didn't have any issues.  Now, when I knit the .Rmd that creates the main html page, the embedded app.R gets cropped at the first dropdown of the sidebar panel or to some fixed non-coded height.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 18.4
- R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
- RStudio Version 1.1.423

[image: mytoybox.online view]

When I click `run app` from r-studio (server version), I see the same result.
[image: Run app view]

Although, from the `run app` view window, if I click the `open in browser` I get the full app as is anticipated
[image: Open in Browser View]

Here is the UI code for the app.R

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel( 
  title = span(img(src="MyToyBox_Logo_5_NoBack.png", width = 40, height = 40), "My Toy Box")
),
sidebarPanel(collapsed = FALSE, width = 3,

  #includeHTML("www/googleAnalytics.html"),

  selectInput(inputId = "distinctSeries", 
              multiple = FALSE,
              label = "Select Series", 
              selected = "The Black Series 6 Inch",
              choices = distinctSeries$seriesName),
  br(),
  uiOutput("figureSelection"),
  br(),
  uiOutput("conditionSelection"),
  br(),
  includeHTML("www/amazonAd.html"),
  includeHTML("www/adSense.html")
),
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Series Average Values", 
             includeHTML("www/googleAnalytics.html"), 
             DT::dataTableOutput("seriesAverageValues") %>% withSpinner(color="#0dc5c1")
             ),
    tabPanel("eBay Sale Scatter Plot",
             includeHTML("www/googleAnalytics.html"),
             h2(textOutput("eBayFigureAverage")),
             plotlyOutput("plotEBayValues") %>% withSpinner(color="#0dc5c1")
             ),
    tabPanel("eBay Sales Table Data", 
             includeHTML("www/googleAnalytics.html"),
              DT::dataTableOutput("tableEBaySaleValues") %>% withSpinner(color="#0dc5c1")
             ),
    tabPanel("Amazon Price Plots",
             includeHTML("www/googleAnalytics.html"),
             h2(textOutput("amazonFigureAverage")),
             plotlyOutput("plotAmazonValues") %>% withSpinner(color="#0dc5c1")
             )
  )
)
)
```

I tried to change the div spacing in the web page, but I just end up getting the cropped app.R view with grey space below the shiny application, so I don't believe the issue in in the web page.

Here is a portion of the web page for completeness

````
---
title: "My Toy Box - Online - A Star Wars Toy Pricing Guide and Archive"
author: "Jason W. Gloor"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%B-%d %H:%M:%S")`'
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true # table of content true
    toc_depth: 3  # upto three depths of headings (specified by #, ## and ###)
    number_sections: false  ## if you want number sections at each table header
    theme: yeti  # many options for theme, this one is my favorite.
    highlight: tango  # specifies the syntax highlighting style
    css: myToyBox.css   # your custom css
  html_notebook: 
    toc: yes
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
```

# My Toy Box - Online - Star Wars Pricing Made Easy {#topTag} 

"My Toy Box On-line" is an interactive site allowing access to view Star Wars figures from the Kenner vintate lines through Hasbro's modern series.  This utility shows figures average estimated value from eBay and current Amazon prices, where available.  Figure values should be used as an estimate.  Amazon prices are updated approimately every 30 minutes.  eBay values are updated approximately each week.

If you are looking for the iOS app, MyToyBox is also available in the [appStore](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-toy-box/id1217665205?mt=8). [See below](#myToyBoxiOS) or click the [MyToyBox iOS](#myToyBoxiOS) Table of Contents Item for more details.

Hi Impact

<iframe src="./starWarsFigureApp" style="border: 1px solid #AAA; width: 100%; height: 940px"></iframe>

# My Toy Box iOS {#myToyBoxiOS}
````

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

When answering the question I wasn't able to see the screenshots you posted, and apparently I misunderstood your problem. When I open your website (on a Mac with Firefox or Safari) then the height of your app does not seem to be a problem. I rather have a white space on the right of your datatable inside your app.

It seems that the appearance of your website differs depending on the browser.

Regarding the white space:
Inspecting the page in Firefox shows that several “td dt-right” are causing the with space. I suspect that the bug is rooted in your datatable definition. Also, when scrolling down in the datatable the title row seems to be off. Maybe some misspecification in the options?

In general it is hard to debug the page/app without a reproducible example and access to all of the code (especially the server side of the app).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Somehow the app started working again without any code changes.  Therefore, I'm not able to determine if this solution will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad bootstrap column class on the right column containing the table.

Change:

`col-sm-8` 
to 
`col-sm-9`

[image]

I don't know much about this platform, but can you add width parameters to MainPanel?

So like the side panel has this:

```
sidebarPanel(collapsed = FALSE, width = 3,
```

Can you do this:

```
mainPanel(width = 9, ..... more stuff below
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Somehow the app started working again without any code changes.  Therefore, I'm not able to determine if this solution will fix the issue.

Comment: Doesn't look working to me when I view it... but ok